# Before upgrading to exchange 2010, is it a must to upgrade all outlook clients in the organization to 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, microsoft-office-2010

I plan on upgrading our current exchange server from 2003 to 2010 and i wanted to know if it's a must to have all clients upgraded to 2010 as i know some of the PC's don't have the required hardware to run office 2010.
Thanks
Itai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a must. Exchange 2010 will work with Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010. And in the worst case, you can take advantage of Outlook Web Access and bypass Outlook on the client side. You'll have the best results with 2007 and 2010, though...

Comment: Thanks for the information, i was wondering about another issue.
In order to install Lync 2010, am i required to have an exchange 2010 server?